# How to set received date for mail in Outlook

Tags: .net, powershell, com, outlook, office-interop

I want to create an email item in Outlook using PowerShell.
I've seen the [SO topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453723/create-outlook-email-draft-using-powershell.), however, I don't understand how to set `ReceivedTime` for a given `MailItem`.

P.S.: I've [written in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.receivedtime.aspx) that member `ReceivedTime` is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem.ReceivedTime` is controlled via the [Exchange Server](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/mailitem-receivedtime-question-t1841273.html). You may look at [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) which uses Extended MAPI to interact with MSG items (*see [experts exchange reference](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Groupware/Outlook/Q_23054925.html)*).