# Get focus on powershell created outlook message

Tags: powershell, outlook, ms-office

I've created a powershell script along [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453723/create-outlook-email-draft-using-powershell) line.

```
$ol=new-object -comobject outlook.application
$mail=$ol.createitem(0)
$mail.subject=(get-content $subject)
$mail.attachments.add($attachment)
$inspector=$mail.getinspector
$inspector.display()
```

But now I'm stuck on the following simple issue:
How do I get focus on the newly created message? Sometimes it does appear in the foreground, but not always. How do I force it to the foreground?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [Inspector.Activate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220325%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method instead of [MailItem.Display()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175266%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in order to bring the mail message window to the foreground. Here's a quote [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175266%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> The Display method is supported for explorer and inspector windows for
>   the sake of backward compatibility. To activate an explorer or
>   inspector window, use the Activate method.

So your script should be:

```
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Activate()
```