# Open outlook's new email dialog with prefilled information from powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I'm trying to write a powershell script (which will run periodicaly) for opening the new email windows of outlook with "to", "subject" and "body" filled with some data.

I found a way to send mails from powershell but you have to send it from powershell. this doesn't fit the need because I have to edit the body of the mail.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "random.dude@email.com"
$Mail.Subject = "data for Subject"
$Mail.Body ="Example of body..."
$Mail.Send()
```

Basicaly what i need is a `$Mail.Show()` wich will open a new e-mail popup with the data pre-filled

powershell is **not** a requirement, it just seams able to manipulate outlook so I tried with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453723/create-outlook-email-draft-using-powershell?rq=1) thread, the `$Mail.Show()` is actually `$Mail.Display()`

Comment: There's always the Mailto URI scheme `mailto:the@dude.org?subject=OhHai&Body=WhatsUp`. From cmd.exe `start "mailto:the@dude.org?subject=OhHai&Body=WhatsUp"`

Comment: Or Send-MailMessage from PowerShell with -Body that you get from a Read-Host variable (or text file?) <- The best part here is that you don't need Outlook at all.

Comment: My preference goes to powershell, but yeah the cmd mailto: could do the trick, thanks for pointing it out!
the point of all that is to have a template of mail showing up at different times; the user should then complete the template. that's why I need the outlook windows to shows up :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late however if you add the following to your script removing your **$Mail.Send()** line it should open the email ready for editing:

```
$mail.save()
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```