# Creating an appointment using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to **create an appointment only using PowerShell**. Is anyone here who knows how to do that?

I've **already tried** to use **EWS**, but I'm not sure how to do that right.

*Thank you for every answer!*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Outlook email draft using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453723/create-outlook-email-draft-using-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear where you run the PowerShell script...

You may consider automating Outlook for creating an appointment item. Read more about that in the [Outlook Email Automation with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/outlook-email-automation-with-powershell/) article.

However, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.